# In systemverilog # delay fails when RHS signal changes faster than delay

Tags: system-verilog

Following code in systemverilog fails:

```
module test_dly;
  reg clk = 0;
  wire w_clk_d;

  always #1ns  clk <= ~clk;
  assign #1400ps w_clk_d = clk;
endmodule
```

I expected that w_clk_d will be delayed version of clk, but it is not.
Seems that # not working if new event arrived before delay expired.
I wrote code to deal with this, but is there way to make # work as expected?
Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

`assign #1400ps w_clk_d = clk;` acts as a delay and filter. When `clk` changes wait 1400ps then then apply the current value (not original value) to `w_clk_d`. If the input changes faster than the delay intimidated values are lost. A similar behavior can also be observed with delay cells in physical circuits.

Filtering can be reduced by chaining smaller delays; the same strategy is used with physical delay cells.

```
wire   #700ps clk_d = clk;
assign #700ps w_clk_d = clk_d;
```

A delay only without filtering can be achieved with a transport delay, which samples the value of `clk` when it toggles, then applies the sampled value to `w_clk_d` 1400ps latter

```
logic w_clk_d;
always @* w_clk_d <= #1400ps clk;
```

To keep the assignment in the schedulers active region then extra code is needed

```
logic w_clk_d;
always @(clk) fork
  begin
    automatic logic sample_clk; // visible only locally with in the fork thread
    sample_clk = clk; // local copy of clk
    #1400ps;
    w_clk_d = sample_clk;
  end
join_none // non-blocking, allows detection of next @(clk)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware of filtering. I implement my delay similar to your sample code, but your sample code more friendly and I will use it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the continuous `assign` statement can only schedule one active assignment at a time. If the RHS of the assignment changes faster than what's known as the *inertial* delay of the continuous assignment, then the previous assignment on the LHS gets canceled or filtered.

What you want is what called *transport* delay: every change on the RHS will get propagated to the LHS. You can do this with a non-blocking assignment (NBA) operator.

```
module test_dly;
  reg clk = 0;
  wire w_clk_d;

  always #1ns  clk = ~clk;
  always @clk  w_clk_d <= #1400ps clk;
endmodule
```